# kubernetes ingress path must end with / to be recognized

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm deploying this list.

1. [Front gist](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/87472125137c00263054b4b6794e5aa5)
2. [Back gist](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/cc643db38d9d02d770bb88924818f456)
3. [MySQL gist](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/6f72db2c5268f7a2596a3e4f0b0569e5)
4. [PhpMyAdmin gist](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/35486ea4eca737072a82152f2d011681)
5. [Ingress gist](https://gist.github.com/darknisfire/41a1aa5ce55b31627a66bf3fe6b790ca)

And Ingress NodePort is `80:31361, 443:30482` in `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx`

The problem is in `Ingress`.

To load `PhpMyAdmin` page, I typed url as `http://my-ip:31361/pma`.

But every resources are not found with 404 error.

If I typed url as `http://my-ip:31361/pma/`, It works finely.

Only difference is `/`.

Why this is happen?

How can I page `pma` or `main`  without `/`?

Comment: What is the path configured in the ingress?

Comment: @Gopi It's `/main(/|$)(.*)`, `/pma(/|$)(.*)`

Comment: Ingress expect regex to be in `RE2` flavor.  you can go to any online tester and put the two URLs and input regex to check which URL is getting match. Eg. try validating here https://regoio.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @P.... Thanks, Test string `/pma` or `/main` is matched but group match is blank

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Nope. just searching nginx-ingress's rewrite and proxy pass.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/646

Comment: @P.... well...i've seen this post, I didn't know how to apply to my yaml. I try some case, finally find solution. I'll post my code as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

kind: Ingress 
metadata:   
  name: ingress   
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^\/(main|pma)$ $1/ permanent; 
spec:   
  rules:
    - http:
      paths:
      - path: /main(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /pma(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: pma-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

As a result, I didn't remove `/`.

However, If user load page as `/main`, nginx will redirect to `/main/`, `/pma` -> `/pma/`.

Then every resouces are accessible.

Thank you @P....